# How to make Rails route to response for the font files (eot)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing, embedded-fonts

In my rails(2.x) application. I want to use custom font in my view. So that I added the font files in public under fonts folder. When I try to get the fonts in url or via application, it through routing error. I guess rails routes not able to recognize the format/file. Correct me if I am wrong and give me solution

css code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Effra';
    src: url('/fonts/effra_std_rg-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/effra_std_rg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('/fonts/effra_std_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('/fonts/effra_std_rg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('/fonts/effra_std_rg-webfont.svg#EffraRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Note: I can able to get woff, ttf file by directly typing the path but not eot file.

```
Error trace:
Unknown action
No action responded to fonts. Actions: XXXXXXsomeactionsXXXXX and rescue_404
```

Thanks in advance,
Arun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the above issue by moving the font folder under public/stylesheets/fonts. and made the above code as below.

```
 font-face {
    font-family: 'Effra';
    src: url('fonts/effra_std_rg-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/effra_std_rg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/effra_std_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/effra_std_rg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/effra_std_rg-webfont.svg#EffraRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Hope this will help to others.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem: Fonts are not being served via the asset pipeline locally (results in a 404 when trying the font path). The above is a workaround, but I'd love to know the actual fix.